# PHP Advanced image processing on upload. No interactive jQuery cropper

Tags: php, image, upload, resize, crop

I'm looking for an advanced all-in-one PHP script that makes everything automatically from the upload of the picture to the file processing and saving. *But I do not want a script with interactive jQuery cropping tool* like [this one](http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery/image_upload_crop.php).

These are the features I'm looking for:

1. Basic HTML upload form (or jquery)
2. File validation (jpg or png)
3. Resize file IF max width is exceeded
4. Crop file in 3 different sizes
5. Save everything on the server in the right folder (Original or resized Image + 3 crops)

I've checked hundreds of scripts and websites, but none seems to really fit to this scheme. Can someone give me some identical — or similar — scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't give you a php script.. but I do recommend this service: https://transloadit.com

Comment: Looks very nice anyway ! That's a good one, thanks